# Calculating de-cumulatived values in TSQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql

Given a table of cars and their odometer reading at various dates (first of each month), how can I write TSQL (ideally, for use as a SQL Server view) to return the "incremental" values?

In other words, I want the reverse operation from [Calculate a Running Total in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860966/calculate-a-running-total-in-sqlserver).

Example:

On this table:

```
CarId |   Date    | Mileage
---------------------------
    1    1/1/2000    10000
    1    2/1/2000    11000
    1    3/1/2000    12000
    2    1/1/2000    10000
    2    2/1/2000    11001
    2    3/1/2000    12001
    3    1/1/2000    10000
   (missing datapoint for (3, 2/1/2000))
    3    3/1/2000    12000
```

We'd return something like (the details/edge cases are flexible):

```
CarId |   Date    | Delta
---------------------------
    1    1/1/2000    10000
    1    2/1/2000    1000
    1    3/1/2000    1000
    2    1/1/2000    10000
    2    2/1/2000    1001
    2    3/1/2000    1000
    3    1/1/2000    10000
    3    3/1/2000    2000
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same approach as the one from @Richard Deeming, but this one regards possible null values as included in original question.

```
;with cte ( rn, id, date, mileage )
as
(
  select
     row_number() over ( partition by id order by id, date )
     , id
     , date
     , mileage
   from
      cars
   where
      mileage is not null
)
select
  "current".id
  , "current".date
  , delta = isnull( "current".mileage - predecessor.mileage, "current".mileage )
from
  cte as "current"
  left join cte as predecessor
    on "current".id = predecessor.id
    and "current".rn - 1 = predecessor.rn
```

See [SQL-Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d6559/14/0).

Comment: I was assuming that "missing datapoint" meant that there wasn't a row in the table, not that there was a row but the mileage was `NULL`.

Comment: maybe a point-of-view-thing. As commented in your answer, I refered to base-data-insert seen in one of the other answers.

Comment: In my case particularly, we do have records with nulls that should be ignored.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for SQL 2005 or higher:

```
WITH cteData As
(
   SELECT
      CarId,
      Date,
      Mileage,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CarId ORDER BY Date) As RowNumber
   FROM
      dbo.Cars
)
SELECT
   C.CarId,
   C.Date,
   CASE
      WHEN P.CarId Is Null THEN C.Mileage
      ELSE C.Mileage - P.Mileage
   END As Delta
FROM
   cteData As C
   LEFT JOIN cteData As P
   ON P.CarId = C.CarId
   And P.RowNumber = C.RowNumber - 1
ORDER BY
   C.CarId,
   C.Date
;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8780)

**NB:** This assumes that "missing datapoint for (3, 2/1/2000)" means that there is no row in the table for car 3, February 2000.

Comment: @Nico: Really? I've just tried it, and it looks OK to me: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8780

Comment: It depends on base data. I ran your query against data provided by tamago via insert query ( see below ). If NULL value exists, query does not return proper results ( or maybe not the estimated ones ;) ) - if there's no row at all in base data, query runs fine!

Answer (score 1):

Window functions are great.  But SQL Server does not have the one you need until SQL Server 2012.  There, you have the lag function:

```
select t.*,
       (Milage - lag(Milage) over (partition by carId order by date)) as Delta
from t
```

For earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

[trouble uploading query], alas.

```
    select t.*, (Mileage - prevMileage) as Delta
    from (select t.*,     
                 (select top 1 Mileage    from t t2
                  where t2.carId = t.carId and t2.date < t.date order by desc
                ) as prevDelta 
      from t
     ) t
```

Comment: I apologize.  Every time I try to better format that query, StackOverflow gives me an error.

Answer (score 1):

Trying to do this without dependence on any 2012 functions, cursor, while loop, etc.

This works within some limitation -- namely, the null-entry for car#3's entry is a problem for it:

```
DECLARE @cars table ([id] int, [date] smalldatetime, [mileage] int)
INSERT INTO @cars ([id], [date], [mileage])
SELECT 1, '1/1/2000', 10000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '2/1/2000', 11000 UNION ALL
SELECT 1, '3/1/2000', 12000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '1/1/2000', 10000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '2/1/2000', 11000 UNION ALL
SELECT 2, '3/1/2000', 12000 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '1/1/2000', 10000 UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '2/1/2000', NULL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, '3/1/2000', 12000


SELECT t1.id, t1.date, t1.mileage, t2.id, t2.date, t2.mileage, t1.mileage - t2.mileage as miles FROM @cars t1
LEFT JOIN @cars t2
ON t1.id = t2.id
AND t1.date = DATEADD(MONTH,1, t2.date)
```